# Fill column with dictionary values if key can be matched

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a DataFrame, containing "keys" and "values". In another datframe, i have only the keys. I want this second dataframe to fill a new column if the keys can be matched. Better to see on the example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['bla','bla2','hi'], 'value':['hello','morning','random']})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'text':['bla','x','hi','y','bla2','hi','bla']})
```

and i want the output to look like this:

```
df1
    text     value
0   bla      hello
1   x           
2   hi       random  
3   y
4   bla2     morning
5   hi       random
6   bla      hello
```

i thought this would be easiest if i create a dictionary from `df` with `text` as key and `value` as values, which i do with this: `y=pd.Series(df.value.values,index=df.text).to_dict()` which would look like this: `y={'bla': 'hello', 'bla2': 'morning', 'hi': 'random'}`
but now i dont know how to do the "matching"

Comment: can you post the dictionary too

Comment: just did, havent you been able to recreate it with the code provided?

Comment: i have(Thank you for that) i was wondering about the logic you want to implement :)

Comment: ah ok i was just curious  :)

Answer (score 0):

With [`Dataframe.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function:

```
In [70]: df.merge(df1, how='right', on='text').fillna('')                                                                       
Out[70]: 
   text    value
0   bla    hello
1   bla    hello
2  bla2  morning
3    hi   random
4    hi   random
5     x         
6     y
```

Comment: this is basically it. but is it possible to keep the order of df1?